# Navigation tools in 2.8 not working

Tags: 3d-view, camera, navigation

When Im in blender 2.8 I click the tools at the top (the hand and the zoom tool) and they do nothing! I know how to scroll to use them but they don't work. I will build and stuff and then like 5 minutes into it the tools slow done and then they completely stop so then I am unable to move around my world

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I can usually get it back to normal by selecting an object and hitting <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to reset the view to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Or rather than zooming in and out use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (Backtick also know as Acent Grave) and fly with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys